# Prerender and prescroll of webview content

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an application using fragments. One of these fragments a WebView which show some locally generated html content. It could have different size but not too large (1-30kb). When user clicks a button on one fragment (let it be FragmentA) i need to change it with that WebView fragment (FragmentB).

```
How is it going now:
1. Instaniate FragmentB
2. replace FragmentA with FragmentB (user sees blank white screen)
3. FragmentB loads generated html, render it (user sees top of html)
4. Page scrolls down with webView.pageDown(true) (calling it from opPageFinished()) (user sees scrolling animation to the bottom of the page)

How i want it to be:
1. Instaniate FragmentB
2. set it to some invisible container (user still have FragmentA on the screen)
3. it renders html, scrolls it down (same)
4. when page is ready, rendered and scrolled down I hide FragmentA and show FragmentB
```

Any suggestions how I can achieve that?
I tried the second algorithm I described but the problem that it looks like WebView dont want to render and\or scroll content untill the fragment is visible to user.

Comment: I faced the same isse tha you are. You can create a loading spinner when instanciating the fragmentB and then load the url. Then use the WebViewClient.onPageFinished callback to hide the spinner and show the web view. I should say tha you still will se a quick blank page, but it was more acceptable than without the spinner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out myself. The answer is simple.
I'm placing FragmentA and FragmentB inside FrameLayout so that FragmentA is "on top" of FragmentB. So when I need to show B i'm just hide A. That's all. B is always "visible" and can render its content in background behind A.

Answer (score 0):

After the user pressed the button in Fragment A, then I would switch to Fragment B immediately.

Fragment B would contain your webview, and something that overlaps the webview to hide it. It could be anything, even a simple image, or a loading animation. In onPageFinished(), you should call to WebView.pageDown(true), and hide the overlapping layer to show the webview.

Comment: The idea is to keep showing fragment A until fragment B will be completely ready, rendered and scrolled down. Not to show animations in between.